# Jekyll build failed: Liquid Exception: cannot load such file -- yajl

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll

Just recently skanked my PC, and I've not used Jekyll in a while, or indeed Ruby, however after thinking I'd set up everything correctly, when I try and run...

> jekyll build or 
>   jekyll serve

I get this error:

```
Generating...   Liquid Exception: cannot load such file -- yajl/2.0/yajl i
n _posts/2013-09-21-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in `require': c
annot load such file -- yajl/2.0/yajl (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in
 `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/yajl-ruby-1.1.0-x86-mingw32/lib
/yajl/yajl.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in
 `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in
 `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/yajl-ruby-1.1.0-x86-mingw32/lib
/yajl.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:118:i
n `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:118:i
n `rescue in require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:124:i
n `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/pygments.rb-0.5.4/lib/pygments/
popen.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:114:i
n `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:114:i
n `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/pygments.rb-0.5.4/lib/pygments.
rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:66:in
 `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:66:in
 `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-1.3.1/lib/jekyll/tags/hi
ghlight.rb:52:in `render_pygments'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-1.3.1/lib/jekyll/tags/hi
ghlight.rb:45:in `render'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/liquid-2.5.4/lib/liquid/block.r
b:106:in `block in render_all'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/liquid-2.5.4/lib/liquid/block.r
b:93:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/liquid-2.5.4/lib/liquid/block.r
b:93:in `render_all'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/liquid-2.5.4/lib/liquid/block.r
b:82:in `render'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/liquid-2.5.4/lib/liquid/templat
e.rb:124:in `render'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/liquid-2.5.4/lib/liquid/templat
e.rb:132:in `render!'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-1.3.1/lib/jekyll/convert
ible.rb:88:in `render_liquid'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-1.3.1/lib/jekyll/convert
ible.rb:150:in `do_layout'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-1.3.1/lib/jekyll/post.rb
:259:in `render'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-1.3.1/lib/jekyll/site.rb
:241:in `block in render'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-1.3.1/lib/jekyll/site.rb
:240:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-1.3.1/lib/jekyll/site.rb
:240:in `render'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-1.3.1/lib/jekyll/site.rb
:39:in `process'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-1.3.1/lib/jekyll/command
.rb:18:in `process_site'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-1.3.1/lib/jekyll/command
s/build.rb:23:in `build'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-1.3.1/lib/jekyll/command
s/build.rb:7:in `process'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-1.3.1/bin/jekyll:77:in `
block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/c
ommand.rb:180:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/c
ommand.rb:180:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/c
ommand.rb:155:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/r
unner.rb:402:in `run_active_command'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/r
unner.rb:66:in `run!'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/d
elegates.rb:7:in `run!'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/i
mport.rb:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

I think it's related to pygments.rb somehow. If i remove the first post that has the syntax highlighting demo, the build works. I've attemped to update pgyments to 0.5.4 but this seemed to make no different. I think got an error that pygments.rb is locked to 0.3.4:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
You have requested:
  pygments.rb ~> 0.5.4

The bundle currently has pygments.rb locked at 0.3.7.
Try running `bundle update pygments.rb`
```

Can anyone shed any light on this? It's driving me nuts. Running Ruby 2.0.0p353.

Comment: Have you run `bundle`?  Or tried `gem install yajl`?

Comment: Yes both, yajl fails as it says: ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'yajl' (>= 0) in any repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered a similar problem today when trying to setup Octopress/Jekyll.

Here is the solution I found.

**Step 1**

Go to your ruby gems directory. 
In my case it's located at `C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems`

Look for yajl.

[image: image1]

You will see a folder called `yajl-ruby-1.1.0-x86-mingw32`

You may or may not see one called `yajl-ruby-1.2.1`

The one with a *-ruby-1.1.0-x86-mingw32* tail is the default. And leads to the error.

What we want to use is the other version

**Step 2**

If you do not have the **none** *mingw32* version, run

```
gem install yajl-ruby
```

This will install the latest version.

In my case the latest version was 1.2.1

**Step 3**

Change the default from the *mingw32* version to the current version.

To do so, go to your website's `gemfile.lock` file

Find the line that says `yajl-ruby (1.1.0-x86-mingw32)`

and change it to `yajl-ruby (1.2.1)`

or the respective version you downloaded

[image: img_before]
[image: img_after]

**Step 4**

That's it. It should work now.

Answer (score 3):

I did following

```
gem install rouge
```

and then 
added following line in the  **_config.yml**

```
highlighter: rouge
```

I found this solution from following page's last comment
https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-help/issues/50

Answer (score 0):

[Yajl](http://lloyd.github.io/yajl/) itself is a “*small event-driven (SAX-style) JSON parser written in ANSI C*.” You are supposed to install it on your Windows box (I’m not sure if there are binary downloads available, possibly you are to download sources and compile them with your preferred `C` compiler) *before* trying to install `yajl-ruby` gem, which is simply the binding to it.

Another option is to install Ruby development kit, refer to [this manual](http://flatshaded.com/2013/05/installing-jekyll-on-windows/) for detailed explanation.

Comment: I've installed the devkit but it's not solved the issue for me

Comment: I was not in touch with windows for years, but would you try to call `yajl --version` and install yajl from sources if it is `<= 2.0`?

Comment: @Mat-visual And, BTW, does `yajl-ruby` gem install extensions without problems?